# Please Suggest an Efficient way to write this code.. For loops takes long time to process

Tags: python, pandas

I have to compare `df1["col1"]` with dictionary `key(K)`, if `df1["col1"]` contains the key, then I want the dictionary `value(v)` in new column in df1.

I wrote the following code, it works but takes a lot of time to complete.
Note:
`df1["col1"]` contains more than 300000 rows and dictionary contains close to 100 key, value pair.

```
for k, v in prefix_dict.items():
    for i in range(len(jul["col1"])):
        if k in jul["col1"][i]:
            jul["newcol"][i] = v
```

I am looking for an alternate way

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please refer to this link on how to ask a question that will get you better responses & good answers https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Can you post some portion of dataframe representing the input & also expected output

Comment: please add a sample input and expected output

Comment: when you say to contains the key, you mean that even if the key is a part of a string inside the cell? or you want to check if it is the same exact key in the dataframe?

Comment: Key is a part of a string inside the cell, preferably as prefix of the cell.